# jQuery making mouseenter and mouse leave events unique

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseenter, mouseleave

I have this code:

```
jQuery(window).one('load',function() {
    var startopen;
    var startclose;
    var delaytime = 350;
    var togglespeed = 'fast';
    jQuery('.hlp').mouseenter(function() {
        var v = "#" + jQuery(this).parent().parent().attr("id") + " .help";
        if( typeof startclose !== undefined) {
            clearTimeout(startclose);
        }
        startopen = setTimeout(function(){
            jQuery(v).fadeIn(togglespeed);
        }, delaytime);
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        var v = "#" + jQuery(this).parent().parent().attr("id") + " .help";
        if( typeof startopen !== undefined) {
            clearTimeout(startopen);
        }
        startclose = setTimeout(function(){
            jQuery(v).fadeOut(togglespeed);
        }, delaytime);
    });
});
```

And when the mouse enters **.hlp**, the **.help** for that particular parent appears, but not before checking to see if the **startclose** variable is defined. When the mouse leaves, the function checks if the **startopen** is defined then sets a timeout for **startclose**. Pretty straight forward.

My issue is simple: when I **mouseenter** one **.hlp** and quickly switch to a nearby **.hlp**, the **startclose** from the first **.hlp** is activated when I **mouseleave** but then the timeout clears when entering the second **.hlp**.

I was thinking of making it uniquely identifiable and since my JS is not what I'd like to call AMAZING, I am asking for suggestions to make this code "more better".

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Store the timerid on each element rather than globally for all. This can be achieved by either using .each(), or by storing the id directly on the element using .data

Comment: Can you give me an example? My jQuery is not good enough for me to fully understand your suggestion.

Comment: @KevinB Are you going to answer ? Or should someboby's else do it ?

Comment: I tend to not answer if the user isn't at least willing to try.

Comment: @KevinB Here I think your comment hasn't been clear enough for a new JS coder. That's why I answered. But I understand your reticence now.

Comment: I agree, i was too short and not descriptive enough to expect that.

Comment: I also did try it several times but to no avail. This is why I posted again. Should I have made it more clear about me being a n00b JS coder?

Comment: I think being a n00b is irrelevant, just show us what you've tried. Asking us to help you make your code better isn't really the right way to ask, instead, point out what your code is currently doing and what you want it to do instead, and then include what you've attempted toward accomplishing that. It sounds like a lot, but sometimes by taking these steps, you'll end up solving it yourself before you click submit.

Comment: I will keep that in mind next time I ask a question. Thanks for the helpful information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea, expressed by Kevin in comment, is to use a closure to associate specific timer variables to each element.

Change

```
jQuery('.hlp').mouseenter(function() {
    var v = "#" + jQuery(this).parent().parent().attr("id") + " .help";
    if( typeof startclose !== undefined) {
        clearTimeout(startclose);
    }
    startopen = setTimeout(function(){
        jQuery(v).fadeIn(togglespeed);
    }, delaytime);
}).mouseleave(function(){
    var v = "#" + jQuery(this).parent().parent().attr("id") + " .help";
    if( typeof startopen !== undefined) {
        clearTimeout(startopen);
    }
    startclose = setTimeout(function(){
        jQuery(v).fadeOut(togglespeed);
    }, delaytime);
});
```

to

```
jQuery('.hlp').each(function(){
  var startopen, startclose;   
  jQuery(this).mouseenter(function() {
    var v = "#" + jQuery(this).parent().parent().attr("id") + " .help";
    if( typeof startclose !== undefined) {
        clearTimeout(startclose);
    }
    startopen = setTimeout(function(){
        jQuery(v).fadeIn(togglespeed);
    }, delaytime);
  }).mouseleave(function(){
    var v = "#" + jQuery(this).parent().parent().attr("id") + " .help";
    if( typeof startopen !== undefined) {
        clearTimeout(startopen);
    }
    startclose = setTimeout(function(){
        jQuery(v).fadeOut(togglespeed);
    }, delaytime);
  });
});
```

Comment: I just did. Thanks @dystroy for helping me adjust to the ways of stackoverflow! :)